# OSM to CSV with OSMCONVERT gives my "empty" amenities

Tags: csv, openstreetmap, export-to-csv

I'm trying to convert my country's Open Street Map data to a CSV file which I can then load in tableau and map businesses.

I downloaded osmconvert, which seems to be the default tool for this process.

Then I downloaded the Dominican Republic's data from this URL:
http://download.geofabrik.de/central-america/haiti-and-domrep.html

When I run the following command:

```
osmconvert64.exe data.osm --csv="@id @lon @lat @amenity @name @shop" --csv-headline --csv-separator=, -o=outfile.csv
```

I get a sheet like this:
[Picture of excel sheet with empty columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmQjz.png)

I seem to get the ID, Latitude and Longitude data right, but get empty amenity, name, and shop columns.

Am I writing the command wrong? I'd appreciate any help, since I can't seem to find an user-friendly tutorial on using this tool on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with osmconvert but as far as I know it will generate an entry for each element in the input file. Most elements from the input file won't have a amenity, name or shop tag. That's why you get so many empty columns. I guess you have to specify an additional filter to get only elements with an amenity or shop tag, possibly with the help of osmfilter.

Alternatively just use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and perform a simple [query](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Usage_examples:_Simple_queries_for_tags_and_bounding_boxes) for all elements with an amenity or shop tag. Overpass API is also able to generate [CSV output](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out.29).